# couldn't setup local SOCKS5 proxy on port 7777: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: openfire

while sending meessage from agent present in spark to client present in client application

im getting following error

couldn't setup local SOCKS5 proxy on port 7777: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

the code i wrote for sending message to client is .. bellow..

i wrote the following method in the class, implemented org.jivesoftware.smackx.workgroup.agent.OfferListener

```
Message message1 = new Message();
message1.setBody(message);
try {
for (MultiUserChat muc : GlobalUtils.getMultiuserchat()) {
   if (muc.getRoom().equals(conf)) {
      muc.sendMessage(message1);
      System.out.println("message sent  ############# agent to client..");
   }
}

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("exception while sending message in sendMessage() ");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

help me

thanks 
rajesh.v

Answer (score 8):

it was because you was running your server with your client on the same machine.

You know... I assume you use openfire for the server..
Openfire use port 7777 by default for file transfer proxy service and it was enabled by default.
and your client do the same by using the port 7777 for the default file transfer.

look at openfire setting at the Server Settings > File Transfer Setting.
You can disable it.
or just run your client and your server on different machine.
I think you are in development state so your server and your client on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

What is the payload of your message - are there any & in it - not sure why, but this seems to trip up smack